# What causes my page to have so much paint time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

From what I read, opacity should be a save css property to change. The display property is only changed at the start and end of the animation. There are only a few css properties in the entire document yet this just baffles me. Why does my paint time still nearly hit the 60fps mark?

[My paint graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz5Ju.png)

```js
(function() {
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
  for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame =
      window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }

  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
          callback(currTime + timeToCall);
        },
        timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };

  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());

function ease(t) {
  return t < .5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t
}

(function(w, d) {

  var toggle = 0,
    fadeId,
    overlay = d.getElementById('overlay'),
    o_style = overlay.style;

  function addEvent(elm, evt, fnc) {
    return w.addEventListener ? elm.addEventListener(evt, fnc, false) : elm.attachEvent(evt, fnc);
  }

  var cur_opacity = 0,
    factor = 400,
    start_time,
    time_Δ,
    dur,
    b,
    Δ;

  function loop(time) {

    if (!start_time) start_time = time; // set time if not set

    time_Δ = time - start_time + 16; // calculate passed time

    cur_opacity = ease(time_Δ / dur) * Δ + b;
    // calculate opacity

    if (time_Δ < dur) {
      fadeId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    } else {
      if (Δ > 0) {
        cur_opacity = 1;
      } else {
        cur_opacity = 0;
        o_style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    o_style.opacity = cur_opacity;

  }

  function fade() {
    if (fadeId) cancelAnimationFrame(fadeId);
    toggle ? toggle = 0 : toggle = 1;

    b = cur_opacity; // set current opacity as base
    Δ = toggle - cur_opacity; // set change we make
    dur = factor * Math.abs(Δ); // set the animation duration

    start_time = 0; // reset time
    o_style.display = 'block'; // always show overlay first
    fadeId = requestAnimationFrame(loop); // init animation
  }

  addEvent(d, 'click', function(event) {
    if (fadeId) cancelAnimationFrame(fadeId);
    fadeId = requestAnimationFrame(fade);
  })

}(window, document))
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #444;
  height: 100%;
}
#overlay {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

*edit: Removed toFixed(). Wrong implementation but not relevant to the issue;

*edit2: I found that adding transform:translateZ(0); to #overlay completely removed the paint time.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "paint time" exactly? What does "nearly hit the 60fps mark" mean?

Comment: In chrome dev tools you can hit F12 and if you view the page in devtools while animating, you will see that the green bars(see image) nearly hit the 60fps mark. I would like to push these bars down, but have no clue what causes this.

Comment: Performance is going to depend a lot on the hardware and software that's running the web page...

Comment: The post has a small DOM tree included which I'm currently cultivating so there's that. Anyways you guys read this: [high-performance-animations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/). If you guys had every looked at the devtools timeline properly, you'd have figured that a paint and/or reflow time of more than 16ms may cause a stuttering delay called [jank](http://jankfree.org/). I was not asking for structuring advice. I was asking clearly what caused the spike in my graph.

Answer (score 1):

CSS **reflows** are CPU intensive as they are caused by the browser having to re-render the entire page in order to update any styling applied by to the UI. A CSS repaint is good. CSS **Repaints** are good as the browser is able to update just the elements that have changed and are much, much less CPU intensive.

Your 60fps number is **good**, more frames mean a smoother animation. From a quick look around it seems Chrome has a hardcoded 60fps cap in place, Chrome will render your animation as quickly as it can using resources at its disposal in order to achieve as smooth an animation as possible, being in mind the simplicity of the animation and how consistently its able to hit 60fps it is unlikely that this short animation actually puts any significant on your machine (in a brief test, spamming the transition on my machine, Chrome never goes over 4% CPU) and so corrective action is not necessary.

Comment: I found what I was looking for. It appears adding `transform: translateZ(0);` completely clears the paint time. I respect your well intended input, but your second paragraph ignores the exponential effect on older devices and it also ignores that fact that this code was only a small part of a bigger webpage.